# For loop must have an iterator()

Tags: kotlin

I need this service in which if the person stays for longer than 30 minutes, they have to pay an extra $10 every 15 minutes (and for the fraction of the 15 as well).

I designed it like this so far:

```
var checkInTime: Calendar
val totalTime: Long
        get() = (Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis - checkInTime.timeInMillis) / MIN_IN_MILISEC

fun getTime(totalTime:Long): Int{
        var finalPrice = 0
        var initialPrice = 20

        if(totalTime<31){

            finalFee = initialPrice
        } else {
            val extraPrice = 10
            
            val extraTime = 15

            finalFee = initialPrice
            for(extraTime in totalTime){
                finalFee += extraTime

        }
        return finalFee
}
```

I get the error "For loop must have an iterator()" when I try to loop through the totalTime when it's more than 30 minutes so that I can add $10 every 15 extra minutes. I need some help as to how to add to the finalFee every extra 15 minutes the person stays since my method is not working.
Thank you.

Comment: extraTime is just a val not a list or something that implements an iterator

Comment: For loops iterate over iterable objects, such ad lists or arrays. Here you're trying to iterate over `totalTime` which is not iterable as it's a Long val, so it doesn't implement an iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at your `getTime` function:

- You're using a `Long` as `totalTime`. You can measure it in minutes to simplify your calculation (since all time values are measured in minutes). Since a `Long` type in Kotlin stores a integer up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 and no soul on Earth will use your service for that long (this represents 17 billion milleniums), you can just use an `Int`.
- You're not declaring the `finalFee` variable, thus the code will raise an
  "Unresolved reference" error. Since you're not using the `finalPrice` variable, I'm assuming you wanted to use this instead.
- You're trying to iterate over a numeric value (in this case, `totalTime`, which is a `Long`). You can iterate over each element of a `List`, but how would you iterate over each element of an integer? I'm assuming you want to do a certain action `totalTime` number of times. In this case, you would use [ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ranges.html).
- You're also not using the variables `extraPrice` and `extraTime`.
- There's code that's common to both if-else conditions (`finalPrice = initialPrice`), so you can extract that to outside the if-statement.

Refactoring your function:

```kotlin
fun getTime(totalTime: Int): Int {
    var finalPrice = 20
    if (totalTime >= 30) {
        (0 until totalTime).forEach {
            finalPrice += 15
        }   
    }
    return finalPrice
}
```

It's shorter, but still doesn't do what it's supposed to: let's suppose `totalTime` is equal to 45. The person got 30 minutes costing $20 and only have to pay $10 for every 15 minutes, therefore will only pay $30 total. Your function is considering that the person will have to pay $15 for *every* minute they stayed, because it uses a for-loop that goes from 0 to `totalTime`. For that, you need a for-loop that goes from 30 (the time limit) from the total time (the `totalTime`) every 15 minutes:

```kotlin
fun getTime(totalTime: Int): Int {
    var finalPrice = 20
    if (totalTime > 30) {
        (30 until totalTime step 15).forEach {
            finalPrice += 10
        }
    }
    return finalPrice
}
```

Better yet, you don't even need a for-loop, you can just use maths:

```kotlin
fun getTime(totalTime: Int): Int {
    var finalPrice = 20
    if (totalTime > 30) {
        finalPrice += ((totalTime - 30) / 15) * 10
        //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^              Get the exceeding time
        //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        How many 15 minutes are there?
        //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   Put $10 for every 15 minutes
    }
    return finalPrice
}
```

The last part: your question said you need to consider the fraction of 15 as well. Therefore, you need to use a real value, not an integer. Let's change it to a `Double`:

```kotlin
fun getTime(totalTime: Int): Double {
    var finalPrice = 20.0
    if (totalTime > 30) {
        finalPrice += ((totalTime - 30) / 15.0) * 10
    }
    return finalPrice
}
```

Let's test your function:

```
fun main() {
    println(getTime(0))    // Outputs 20.0
    println(getTime(10))   // Outputs 20.0
    println(getTime(30))   // Outputs 20.0
    println(getTime(45))   // Outputs 30.0
    println(getTime(60))   // Outputs 40.0
    println(getTime(70))   // Outputs 46.666...
}
```